# PHP/arrays : Special condition in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a booking search result with an array to list users from the search form.

Example :
After search1 with 1 adult and 2 kids, users array is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => ADULT
    [1] => KID
    [2] => KID
)
```

After second search : 2 adults and 1 kid :

```
Array
(
    [0] => ADULT
    [1] => KID
    [2] => KID
    [3] => ADULT
    [4] => ADULT
    [5] => KID
)
```

After third search : 1 adult, 1 kid and 1 senior

```
Array
(
    [0] => ADULT
    [1] => KID
    [2] => KID
    [3] => ADULT
    [4] => ADULT
    [5] => KID
    [6] => ADULT
    [7] => KID
    [8] => SENIOR
)
```

I'm trying to save users id with special conditions (we take our example):

For the first search, we increment all IDs:

- ADULT (key0) is new > ID take Pax1
- KID (key1) is new > ID take Pax2
- KID (key2) is new > ID take Pax3

Result : **Pax1, Pax2, Pax3**

For the other searchs, we increment by this logic :

Search2:

- ADULT (key3) exists in the users array (key0) > ID take Pax1
- ADULT (key4) is new > ID take Pax4
- KID (key5) exists in the users array (key1)> ID take Pax2

Result :  **Pax1, Pax2, Pax3,Pax1, Pax2, Pax4**

Search3:

- ADULT (key6) exists in the users array (key0) > ID take Pax1
- KID (key7) exists in the users array (key1) > ID take Pax2
- SENIOR (key8) is new > ID take Pax5

Result :  **Pax1, Pax2, Pax3, Pax1, Pax2, Pax4, Pax1, Pax2, Pax5**

My code wich increment all ID ($nbListePaxIN is the users array) :

```
$nbListePaxIN = array_count_values($tabListePaxAll);
$i = 1;
foreach ($tabListePaxAll as $listeIN) {
    if ($listeIN == "ENFANT") {
        if (in_array("ENFANT", $tabListePaxAll)) {
            $idPax = $i;
        } else {
            $idPax = $i;
        }
    } else {
        if (in_array("ADULTE", $tabListePaxAll)) {
            $idPax = $i;
        } else {
            $idPax = $i;
        }
    }

    echo "Pax ".$idPax."<br>";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Sorry, but your examples are rather unclear. Your first array has key 1 KID, but then below you say _ADULT (key1) is new > ID take Pax2_ …? Please _verbally_ describe how you want to come to those results.

Comment: Right. My bad.. Updated.

Comment: And your definition of “being new” is …? If it is just “did that value occur in the array before”, then the first example is _still_ wrong: "KID (key2) is new > ID take Pax3"

Comment: As i said, for the first search result we increment all ID. We apply the conditions for the rest.

Comment: What conditions? Again, what is _your definition_ of “new” in this context?

Comment: Example : New adult = if the number of adults in the current search is > the number of adults that we have in the users arrays. `2 adults in the users arrays` then `new search with 3 adults` => `the 3rd adult is new`